# Continuity of function if $f^2$ and $f^3$ are continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a real valued function. Prove or disprove:  $f$ is continuous if $f^2$ and $f^3$ are continuous. $f^2=(f(x))^2$.

I think $f$ would be continuous. But don't know how to prove it.

Comment: @Pacciu.  Huh?  What does $t$ have to do with anything?

Comment: I don't think you need the assumption on $f^2(x)$.

Comment: @Pacciu That is a neat way of doing it which uses all the information.

Comment: @Pacciu:  So instead of $t = \frac{t^3 + t^2}{t^2+1}$ you really meant $f(x) = \frac{f^3(x) + f^2(x)}{f^2(x) + 1}$?

Comment: @Pacciu: are you sure of your identity?

Answer (score 1):

$f=\sqrt[3]{f^3}$, therefore $f$ is continuous as soon as $f^3$ is.

Comment: To apply this $f$ has to be positive.

Comment: @SumitSah You can take a unique cube root of any real number - I'm not sure why you think $f$ needs to be positive.

Comment: @SumitSah Cube roots work for negative numbers too, you know.

Comment: ah! yes I got it. Thank you.